# Не выравнивается блок внутри блока

Tags: html, css

```css
.footer {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.footer_column {
  margin: 60px auto 40px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 250px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.footer__logo_place_footer {
  width: 183px;
  height: 35px;
}

.footer_social-icon {
  height: 250px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer_column">
    <div class="footer__logo_place_footer"></div>
    <div class="footer_social-icon"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Нужно блок 2(footer_social-icon) передвинуть в право в краю 1(footer_column) , по не выходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста заполните HTML часть вашего сниппета

Comment: заполнил html       код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.footer {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.footer_column {
  margin: 60px auto 40px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.footer__logo_place_footer {
  width: 183px;
  height: 35px;
}

.footer_social-icon {
  height: 250px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer_column">
    <div class="footer__logo_place_footer"></div>
    <div class="footer_social-icon"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: премного благодарен